# How can I fix the 'sha' undefined error for my Netlify site?

Tags: jekyll, netlify, netlify-cms

So I've built a Jekyll site with the theme [Moon](Failed to persist entry: TypeError: Cannot read property 'sha' of undefined) and I've uploaded it to my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/ccsource/CCSource.org/tree/site). Then I want to add Netlify's admin panel to my site so I follow [this guide](https://www.chrisanthropic.com/blog/2018/adding-netlifycms-to-jekyll-secure-with-netlify-identity-git-gateway/) which I modify the `config.yml` to the following code:

```
backend:
  name: git-gateway

publish_mode: editorial_workflow

media_folder: "files"

display_url: https://ccsource.org

slug:
  encoding: "ascii"
  clean_accents: true

collections:
  - name: "story"
    label: "Story"
    folder: "_posts"
    extension: "md"
    slug: "{{year}}-{{month}}-{{day}}-{{slug}}"
    create: true
    fields:
      - {label: "Layout", name: "layout", widget: "hidden", default: "post"}
      - {label: "Title", name: "title", widget: "string"}
      - label: "tags"
        name: "tags"
        widget: "list"
        allow_add: true
        default: ["story"]
      - {label: "Summary", name: "excerpt", widget: "string", required: false}
      - {label: "comments", name: "comments", widget: "hidden", default: true}
      - label: "Publish date"
        name: "date"
        widget: "datetime"
        default: ""
        format: "MMM Do YY"
      - {label: "Body", name: "body", widget: "markdown", required: true}
```

Since I got markdown sample file like:

```
---
layout: post
title:  "Sample"
date:   2016-03-15
excerpt: "Hello..."
tag:
- sample
- post
- video
comments: true
---
# Sample
```

But after all things setup and deployed I visit my site's admin panel and try to create a new post I keep getting the following error.

```
Failed to persist entry: TypeError: Cannot read property 'sha' of undefined
```

And I've googled and modified the `branch` value to `site` which match to my github repository, but the error keeps showing, how can I fix it?

Comment: Firstly, `slug: "---"` definitely won't work. The `slug` setting is to set the filename of post in GitHub. What are you trying to change by setting it, or can it just be removed?

Comment: @tech4him actually according to their [official documentation](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/configuration-options/), the `extension` value determine which extension they should find and `slug` value is what the file name should be call (or aka url slug).

Comment: Looks like you updated your question since @tech4him commented.

I ran your repo locally and all works fine using the GitHub backend. I'm not sure how you're using with the Git Gateway backend since you don't have the identity widget in place. How are you logging in?

Comment: @ShawnErquhart yes I've add a couple more value according to their official document but the error is still showing

Comment: @ShawnErquhart I've tried to remove the `branch` under the `backend` since there isn't a clear documentation of which value should I put there. The backend is using netlify's `git-gateway` not GitHub's service. ([referrence document](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/authentication-backends/))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone else experiencing this, the issue was that Netlify Identity was enabled, but Git Gateway, a sub-feature of Netlify Identity, was not. Instructions for enabling Git Gateway here: https://www.netlify.com/docs/git-gateway/#getting-started